# Error building Erica on Windows

Tags: windows, erlang, couchapp, rebar

I'm trying to play around with a CouchApp, for which erica is apparently the tool to use. Building things from source on Windows is always a nightmare, but I think I've almost got it. I installed the dependencies of Erlang and rebar, then ran `erica\bootstrap.bat`, but I get the following error:

```
C:\Programming\couchapp\erica>bootstrap.bat
==> mochiweb (get-deps)
==> oauth (get-deps)
==> ibrowse (get-deps)
==> couchbeam (get-deps)
==> erica (get-deps)
==> mochiweb (compile)
==> oauth (compile)
==> ibrowse (compile)
==> couchbeam (compile)
==> erica (compile)
c:/Programming/couchapp/erica/src/erica.erl:none: redefining macro 'WITH_MOCHIJSON'
ERROR: compile failed while processing C:/Programming/couchapp/erica: rebar_abort
```

There doesn't appear to be any logs, so does anyone know what might cause this?

I'm on a fresh install of Windows 8 x64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that bootstrap.bat just doesn't work. You need to run this three commands to simulate Makefile behavior:

```
    rebar get-deps
    rebar compile
    escript bootstrap
```

On my Windows 8 it works fine.

Comment: Hah, awesome. That was way easier than I expected. Thanks!